# Javascript Import and Export module

Tags: javascript, function, import, export

What is wrong with this code, why it doesn't console anything.

```
import {say} from 'https://host.nizar.ml/something.js' 
say('something')
```

can anybody explain what is wrong here please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download something.js and declare it via locale (/home/user/desktop/something.js). It should be a URL problem

Edit: I have replicated your code, and it gives me this error on the log: "Access to script at 'host.nizar.ml/something.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." So it must be that you have to enable the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your webpage first

Comment: so you're telling me that nothing is wrong, but just the url. I thought I wrote some wrong syntax or something, thanks I'm trying to figure it out though

Comment: The syntax looks good to me, it doesnt give you a error either right?

Comment: I have replicated your code, and it gives me this error on the log: 
"Access to script at 'https://host.nizar.ml/something.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." So it must be that you have to enable the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your webpage first

Comment: @Lufermy welcome to the community. Could edit your post so that your comment explanation becomes part of the answer?